# Azure B2C Custom policyAn exception occuring while implementing the combinedsignup&signin & invitationURL based signup&signin

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to create a setup where a user can

1. signup & sign in directly from the combined signup&Signin page
2. Signup&signin from the invitation link.

Point one is working perfectly fine using the following files

1. [BaseFile](https://github.com/rbagree/B2CSignupSigninInvite/blob/main/TrustFrameworkBase.xml)
2. [ExtensionFile](https://github.com/rbagree/B2CSignupSigninInvite/blob/main/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml)
3. [RPFile](https://github.com/rbagree/B2CSignupSigninInvite/blob/main/progressive_signup_signin.xml)

For point 2 I have created

1. [SignupinviteRPFile](https://github.com/rbagree/B2CSignupSigninInvite/blob/main/signup_invitation.xml)
   Now, when I click on the invitation URL which is in the following format

[https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_invitation/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientID}&nonce=ca00379642b94aa693a80b66783aa010&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmytenant-dev.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignup%2Fuser-invite&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&id_token_hint={SignedJWTToken}](https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_invitation/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=%7BclientID%7D&nonce=ca00379642b94aa693a80b66783aa010&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmytenant-dev.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignup%2Fuser-invite&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&id_token_hint=%7BSignedJWTToken%7D)

I do get the signup page with readonly emailID. But once I fill all the information and click "Create" it gives me
Following issue:
Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.
We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us. In the meantime, please try again.
Correlation ID: 3a9f35e6-51e1-40b7-9ee9-d9c8081ff8d6
Timestamp: 2021-02-03 11:07:20Z
AADB2C: An exception has occurred.

Observations:

1. The account gets created in the local AD and I can see the user's entry
2. Following are the three calls from the network logger
3. /SelfAsserted?tx=StateProperties=eyJUSUQiOiIzYTlmMzVlNi01MWUxLTQwYjctOWVlOS1kOWM4MDgxZmY4ZDYifQ&p=B2C_1A_signup_invitation

2./confirmed?csrf_token=bThiL2hJNXZ4ZFBwSXZ3ZzRLd1lVUExQV2V1T3EzVkNBYUloaEpqWk5lYTBXczAvUW9oSjJMVXBEWWhrenZ1Ymc2SkJNL3N5N0UxNzZYNHBDVDdsaWc9PTsyMDIxLTAyLTAzVDExOjA2OjQ2LjU5NTgzMzVaO2tuVzlHdzdMTDZ1QzMyT1JmRGNZbGc9PTt7IlRhcmdldEVudGl0eSI6IkxvY2FsQWNjb3VudFNpZ25VcFdpdGhSZWFkT25seUVtYWlsIiwiT3JjaGVzdHJhdGlvblN0ZXAiOjN9&tx=StateProperties=eyJUSUQiOiIzYTlmMzVlNi01MWUxLTQwYjctOWVlOS1kOWM4MDgxZmY4ZDYifQ&p=B2C_1A_signup_invitation&diags=%7B%22pageViewId%22%3A%22e25ebe04-1601-460d-b3a8-1d958c8155b8%22%2C%22pageId%22%3A%22SelfAsserted%22%2C%22trace%22%3A%5B%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T005%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350407%2C%22acD%22%3A3%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T021%20-%20URL%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fmytenant.b2clogin.com%2Fstatic%2Ftenant%2Ftemplates%2FAzureBlue%2FselfAsserted.cshtml%3Fslice%3D001-000%26dc%3DPNQ%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350407%2C%22acD%22%3A50%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T019%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350407%2C%22acD%22%3A8%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T004%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350407%2C%22acD%22%3A2%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T003%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350407%2C%22acD%22%3A2%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T035%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350410%2C%22acD%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T030Online%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350410%2C%22acD%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T017T010%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350438%2C%22acD%22%3A1075%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T002%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350440%2C%22acD%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T017T010%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350438%2C%22acD%22%3A1077%7D%5D%7D

3.client/perftrace?tx=3a9f35e6-51e1-40b7-9ee9-d9c8081ff8d6&p=null
3. Following URL uses GET Method
https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_invitation/api/SelfAsserted/confirmed?csrf_token=bThiL2hJNXZ4ZFBwSXZ3ZzRLd1lVUExQV2V1T3EzVkNBYUloaEpqWk5lYTBXczAvUW9oSjJMVXBEWWhrenZ1Ymc2SkJNL3N5N0UxNzZYNHBDVDdsaWc9PTsyMDIxLTAyLTAzVDExOjA2OjQ2LjU5NTgzMzVaO2tuVzlHdzdMTDZ1QzMyT1JmRGNZbGc9PTt7IlRhcmdldEVudGl0eSI6IkxvY2FsQWNjb3VudFNpZ25VcFdpdGhSZWFkT25seUVtYWlsIiwiT3JjaGVzdHJhdGlvblN0ZXAiOjN9&tx=StateProperties=eyJUSUQiOiIzYTlmMzVlNi01MWUxLTQwYjctOWVlOS1kOWM4MDgxZmY4ZDYifQ&p=B2C_1A_signup_invitation&diags=%7B%22pageViewId%22%3A%22e25ebe04-1601-460d-b3a8-1d958c8155b8%22%2C%22pageId%22%3A%22SelfAsserted%22%2C%22trace%22%3A%5B%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T005%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350407%2C%22acD%22%3A3%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T021%20-%20URL%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fmytenant.b2clogin.com%2Fstatic%2Ftenant%2Ftemplates%2FAzureBlue%2FselfAsserted.cshtml%3Fslice%3D001-000%26dc%3DPNQ%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350407%2C%22acD%22%3A50%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T019%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350407%2C%22acD%22%3A8%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T004%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350407%2C%22acD%22%3A2%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T003%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350407%2C%22acD%22%3A2%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T035%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350410%2C%22acD%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T030Online%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350410%2C%22acD%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T017T010%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350438%2C%22acD%22%3A1075%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T002%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350440%2C%22acD%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22ac%22%3A%22T017T010%22%2C%22acST%22%3A1612350438%2C%22acD%22%3A1077%7D%5D%7D

Gives following message:
We can't sign you in
Your browser is currently set to block JavaScript. You need to allow JavaScript to use this service.

To learn how to allow JavaScript or to find out whether your browser supports JavaScript, check the online help in your web browser.

And the last call uses POST method
https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_invitation/client/perftrace?tx=3a9f35e6-51e1-40b7-9ee9-d9c8081ff8d6&p=null

gives 404 error message

Basically, after the signup from the invitation url I am not able to signin to my application. I am not sure if there is any conflict between the two RP files or If I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here
https://github.com/rbagree/B2CSignupSigninInvite/blob/main/signup_invitation.xml#L63

The log shows it cannot find this key. Just remove this entire technical profile as it should already exist in your base file.